# Transaction failed. The server response was: Sending address not accepted due to spam filter

Tags: asp.net, smtp

Can any one tell why this exception raises please. I wrote the below code

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    try
    {
        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(Textemail.Text, Textfname.Text);

        smtpClient.Host = "mail.paymycheck.info";

        //Default port will be 25

        smtpClient.Port = 587;


        message.From = fromAddress;


        message.To.Add("support@paymycheck.info");
        message.Subject = "Feedback";

        message.CC.Add("support@paymycheck.info");
        message.IsBodyHtml = false;

        message.Body = Textcomments.Text;

        smtpClient.Send(message);


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```

I am getting the exception as i specified

Answer (score 1):

Because your **IP address (the server that run this asp.net and try to send the email) have been black listed as spammer** and blocked by the mail server.

If you believe that this is an error you can contact the provider to remove your from the black list. If you try to run this from dynamically change ip, from your home, then close and reconnect to get a new ip to make your test and maybe the new one is not black listed.

You can make a test here http://checkmyip.com/

In the odd case that you try to send email to your self... and you blocked by your self, go to your mail server and add to white list your local host ip address.